# How to show XPath for current location in an XML hierarchy in the modeline?

Tags: mode-line, xml

When editing a long Maven `pom.xml` I may see a screen full of `<plugin>` blocks with their parent tags out of sight. I would like to know whether I'm looking at a `/project/build/plugins/plugin` tag or a `/project/profiles/profile/build/plugins/plugin` tag.

Is there an easy way to display this information in the modeline or on the top of the screen?

Comment: Have you seen https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NxmlMode#toc11 ?

Comment: @omajid: Please consider posting that as an answer: summarizing that info and providing the link there.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, but I percieve this functionality to be so basic that I find it hard to believe there isn't a ready-made solution. If I would like to see the context hierarchy in C++, `which-func-mode` is ready to use. If I would like to do the same in XML, do I really have to define a function myself? And actually the linked function just prints this info to the echo area on demand, even more code is needed to make it show up in the modeline permanently. Isn't there a Melpa package that provides this functionality?

Comment: I looked into `which-func-mode` and found that it is extensible by custom functions, so all that is needed to get the `nxml-where` function work with `which-func-mode` is `(add-hook 'which-func-functions 'nxml-where)`. @omajid if you combine these two pieces of information into an answer, I am happy to accept it.

Comment: Since nobody added an answer but I found the solution, I answered my own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install [`nxml-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NxmlMode) and [`which-function-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhichFuncMode). Take the `nxml-where` function from [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NxmlMode#toc11) and add it to your `.emacs` file followed by:

```
(defun xml-find-file-hook ()
  (when (derived-mode-p 'nxml-mode)
    (which-function-mode t)
    (setq which-func-mode t)
    (add-hook 'which-func-functions 'nxml-where t t)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'xml-find-file-hook t)
```

Comment: any idea why using nxml-mode-hook doesn't work?

Comment: to answer my own question, (which-func-ff-hook) get called by after-change-major-mode-hook, and it sets which-func-mode back to nil